# What are these dark lines in IRIS images of the sun?

Tags: the-sun, space-telescope

Dark, narrow, straight lines move around within images from [Interface Region Imaging Spectrograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Region_Imaging_Spectrograph) (IRIS) in such a way that they appear intentional and systematic, and not just some imaging artifact as discussed in [this SDO question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15370/12102) and [this SOHO question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15427/12102).

What causes this line?

[image]

[image]

**above:** screen shots from YouTube videos of IRIS imagery.

**below:** The full YouTube videos of IRIS imagery.

[image]

**above:** Photograph of IRIS from the detailed article about the IRIS' optical instrumentation at [Spaceflight 101](http://spaceflight101.com/iris/spacecraft-instruments/). Photo credit LMSAL.

[image]

**above:** Details of IRIS' Spectrograph and Slit-Jaw Imager from the article about the IRIS' optical instrumentation at [Spaceflight 101](http://spaceflight101.com/iris/spacecraft-instruments/). Image credit NASA/LMSAL.

Comment: There is a lot of stuff contained in the optical path in the telescope: http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/iris/spacecraft/index.html I guess the line is part of a grid holding some component. It appears moving because the telescope is moving and the images have been realigned when making the video. Couldn't find a definitive answer...

Comment: @asdfex there is *a lot more* information in the [Spaceflight 101](http://spaceflight101.com/iris/spacecraft-instruments/) article! This is a fairly in-depth description of the complex optical system, but I still can't pinpoint what is really going on here. Remember, this dark line is *in focus* at the same time as the sun, so you can't just look for something just anywhere in the optical path, it is most likely happening at some intermediate focal plane.

Comment: Didn't find more hints in https://iris.lmsal.com/documents/iris_csr_instrument.pdf 
It's not a segmented CCD. It can be an artifact of the scanning procedure. The CCDs have 2 MPixel only, but the images seem to be higher resolution. Maybe it's just a gap between two scanning rows. Or even a broken row of the CCD itself

Comment: @asdfex look more closely - I think you found it! "**E.6.1.3 UV Slit-jaw Imager Optical Design.** The slit-jaw imager optics re-image the solar image reflected from the slit jaws onto a CCD detector." The slit jaws are mirrors!?!

Comment: @asdfex also [from here](http://iris.lmsal.com/itn26/introduction.html#iris-instrumentation): "Slit-Jaw Imager (SJI): reflected off the reflective area around the slit ('slit-jaw'), passing through or reflected off broadband filters on a filterwheel, then onto 1 CCD to produce an image of the scene around the slit (slit-jaw = SJI) in 6 different filters (2 for calibration, 4 for solar images, Table 2)" I think these are good enough for you (or someone) to write a nice answer. An abundance of info here too: https://iris.lmsal.com/itn26/itn26.pdf including discussion of the rastering!

Comment: You're right. The black area is the part of the image that is cut out to be sent to the spectrograph and therefore is missing in the CCD images. Section 1.4.2 of your "from here" link makes it clear.

Comment: Videos help to illustrate the rastering - I had to right-click and download as mp4 and view offline, the viewer in the pages didn't work for me. Start from **1 October 2013: Quicklook slit-jaw movies available** at http://iris.lmsal.com/  -  or here is just an example:  http://www.lmsal.com/solarsoft//irisa/data/level2_nrt/2016/09/20/20160920_054022_3660109230/www/l2_20160920_054022_3660109230_SJI_1330_t000_fits_20160920_054022_m.mp4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@uhoh found the answer in one of the publications on the optical system of IRIS:

The IRIS telescope has two major measuring devices: First, an imaging device that can take normal photos of the surface of the sun in several different spectral bands. This is the source of the videos shown in the two videos.

The second device is the source of the black line in these pictures: A slit spectrometer. It consists of a slit jaw (two metal plates forming a narrow aperture) to cut out one line of the image of the sun and a prism that spreads the light depending on its wavelength. A usual CCD sensor is then used to measure the spectral distribution of the incoming light with high resolution.

The front of the slit jaw consists of mirrors to reflect the remaining light onto the imaging sensor. Naturally, this reflection misses the light that is used for the spectrometer and shows a black line as can be seen in the pictures. In order to gather spectral information across the whole surface of the Sun, the telescope turns slowly, selecting a different part for each successive image.

A rather extensive description of the optical system can be found in this [publication](https://iris.lmsal.com/documents/iris_csr_instrument.pdf)

The scanning across the sun surface can be seen in this [animation](http://www.lmsal.com/solarsoft/irisa/data/level2_nrt/2016/09/20/20160920_072933_3610091469/www/l2_20160920_072933_3610091469_SJI_1400_t000_fits_20160920_072933_j.html).

Comment: Thanks! I think the prism is called 'a pre-disperser', and the two spectrometers use highly dispersive diffraction gratings (3,600 lines/mm).. Also it looks like the fast scanning within the FOV is done with the active secondary mirror (sect. E.6.1.9 1st paragraph), but yep, the whole telescope does have to move to target different areas on the sun.